# Unable to redirect to https for EKS Load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I am not able to redirect traffic from http to https in my EKS service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ledger-admin
  name: ledger-admin
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:52943:certificate/01143f-XXX
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: admin-test-com
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: admin.test.com
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: ledger-admin
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I tried adding the annotation

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
```

but it also didnt work. When i enter https://admin.test.com directly in address bar its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K8s **Service** does not have redirection functionality. it is designed to provide a static IP (or, cluster IP level) to the pods who has ephemeral IP. It allows pods to have service discovery functionality in the cluster. A Kubernetes service is private to the cluster. This means only applications inside the cluster can access them. There are a number of ways around this, and one of the best is an ingress.

Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Using the **Ingress** resource, you just do `"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect" = "443"`